# Saving a Keras/Sklearn in python and loading the saved model in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, tensorflow.js

I have a trained sklearn SVM model in .pkl format and a Keras .h5 model. Can I load these models using **tensorflow.js** on a browser? 
I do most of my coding in python and not sure how to work with tensorflow.js
My model saving code looks like this

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib 

joblib.dump(svc,'model.pkl') 
model = joblib.load('model.pkl')  
prediction = model.predict(X_test) 

#------------------------------------------------------------------

from keras.models import load_model

model.save('model.h5')  
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Comment: I am not sure about the sklearn model. But I am very sure  you can convert the .h5 model to a .pb file and convert the .pb file to tflite which can be used in tensorflow.js. check this one..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256877/how-to-convert-kerash5-file-to-a-tflite-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to deploy your model with tensorflow-js, you need to use the `tensorflowjs_converter`, so you also need to install the `tensorflowjs` dependency.

You can do that in python via  `pip install tensorflowjs`.

Next, you convert your trained model via this operation, according to your custom names: `tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras /tmp/model.h5 /tmp/tfjs_model`, where the last path is the output path of the conversion result.

Note that, after the conversion you will get a `model.json` (architecture of your model) and a list of N shards (weights split in N shards).

Then, in JavaScript, you need to us the function `tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL)`, where MODEL_URL is the url pointing to your model.json. Ensure that, at the same location with the model.json, the shards are also located.

Since this is an asynchronous operation(you do not want your web-page to get blocked while your model is loading), you need to use the JavaScript `await` keyword; hence `await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL)`

Please have a look at the following link to see an example:  https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion

Comment: I think tensorflow_js works only for TensorFlow and Keras models, there is nothing mentioned about other types/formats in the documentation.