# TFlite model vs Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have a keras model saved in h5 format as 'model.h5'. I have converted it into tflite form 'model.tflite'. When I run the tflite  model with a test image, it gives same result with any image.

```
img = cv2.imread("dog.jpeg")
img = cv2.resize(img, (300,300))
img = np.array(img, dtype="float32")
img = np.reshape(img, (1,300,300,3))


# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']

print("*"*50, input_details)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

The result i get irrespective of image is -
`[[0.9999]]`

Comment: What does print(output_details) give?

Comment: @Farmaker [{'name': 'serving_default_conv2d_43_input:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 300, 300,   3]), 'shape_signature': array([ -1, 300, 300,   3]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

Comment: is this for output???

Comment: @Farmaker [{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0', 'index': 32, 'shape': array([1, 1]), 'shape_signature': array([-1,  1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

Comment: It seems right. What are you expecting for outputs? What is your Keras model output?

Comment: @Farmaker the keras model is a prediction model. Basically it has to predict between dogs and cats. Model gives 1 for dogs and 0 for cats. After converting the model to tflite, whatever be the image, the output it gives is 0.99.

Comment: So, it seems a classification problem with 2 outputs...but you have 1 output. Can you check again? How many nodes do you have for outputs?

Comment: After following Farmaker's suggestion, you can follow a few more sanity checks:
1. Have you tested with keras model (.h5) as well? This is to eliminate the possibility that the original model itself is faulty.
2. Double check that the conversion was done correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256877.